# SQL listing of Employees currently clocked in

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a list of employees currently clocked into our factory.
The clocking transactions update the clocking table with :
'dayreviewinoutflag = 0' for clocking IN and 'dayreviewinoutflag = 1' for clocking OUT
I want to look back the last 72 hours to get the latest IN clocking for an employee where 
their last clocking was not an OUT clocking.

I feel the query below is nearly there, but....

```
SELECT cc.* 
FROM   clocking cc 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT employeecode, 
                          Max(clockingdatetimeunrounded) AS MaxDateTime, 
                          CASE 
                            WHEN clocking.dayreviewinoutflag = 0 THEN Max( 
                            clockingdatetimeunrounded) 
                            ELSE NULL 
                          END                            AS InDateTime, 
                          CASE 
                            WHEN clocking.dayreviewinoutflag = 1 THEN Max( 
                            clockingdatetimeunrounded) 
                            ELSE NULL 
                          END                            AS OutDateTime 
                   FROM   clocking 
                   WHERE  clockingdatetimeunrounded >= 
                          Dateadd(hour, -72, Getdate()) 
                   GROUP  BY employeecode) groupedcc 
               ON cc.employeecode = groupedcc.employeecode 
                  AND cc.clockingdatetimeunrounded = groupedcc.maxdatetime 
                  AND groupedcc.indatetime > groupedcc.outdatetime
```

At this point I'm getting an error about an aggregate function or GROUP BY, but if i try and add the 'dayreviewinoutflag' into the GROUP it get no results.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

The table data below should result in EMPLOYEECODE 11307 not being returned in results list

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| AUTONUMBER    EMPLOYEECODE    CLOCKINGDATETIMEUNROUNDED       DAYREVIEWINOUTFLAG |
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| 208945        11307           2015-11-10 17:31:00.000         1                  |
| 209284        11307           2015-11-11 07:59:00.000         0                  |
| 209372        11307           2015-11-11 17:01:00.000         1                  |
| 210162        11307           2015-11-13 07:30:00.000         0                  |
| 210185        11307           2015-11-13 10:30:00.000         1                  |
+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: `Max(clockingdatetimeunrounded)` - shouldn't you have included `clockingdatetimeunrounded` in your `GROUP BY` as well?

Comment: post up some sample data from each table

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl `clockingdatetimeunrounded` is being aggregated so should not require grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you are using `clocking.dayreviewinoutflag` in your query, so it must be included in your `GROUP BY` clause.

The query you've written however won't achieve your goal, your inner select is attempting to get the last in/out datetime for an employee simultaneously. You need to split those queries into separate queries and then join them to compare:

```
WITH cte_LastClockIn AS
(
    SELECT employeecode, 
          Max(clockingdatetimeunrounded) AS InDateTime, 
    FROM   clocking 
    WHERE  clockingdatetimeunrounded >= 
          Dateadd(hour, -72, Getdate())
    AND clocking.dayreviewinoutflag = 0
    GROUP  BY employeecode
)

,cte_LastClockOut AS
(
    SELECT employeecode, 
          Max(clockingdatetimeunrounded) AS OutDateTime, 
    FROM   clocking 
    WHERE  clockingdatetimeunrounded >= 
          Dateadd(hour, -72, Getdate())
    AND clocking.dayreviewinoutflag = 1
    GROUP  BY employeecode
)


SELECT 
    cc.* 
FROM clocking cc 

INNER JOIN cte_LastClockIn lci
ON cc.employeecode = lci.employeecode
AND cc.clockingdatetimeunrounded = lci.InDateTime

INNER JOIN cte_LastClockOut lco
ON cc.employeecode = lco.employeecode

WHERE lci.InDateTime > lco.OutDateTime
```

Comment: Dear Wibbler, thank you for taking the time and effort into providing this excellent solution - it's a very much appreciated.